# Запрет определённого тел номера в input [HTML, JS]

Tags: javascript, php, html

Как запретить ввод определённого телефонного номера в input?

Comment: Вас интересует  формат номера или определённый номер телефона?

Comment: Определённый номер телефона

Comment: на input повесить событие keypress(кажется) и если event.target.value === 'номер телефона', то показывать ошибку, очищать поле или каким-то другим образом запрещать

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!

Comment: на сервере надежней

Comment: а лучше и на клиенте и на сервере